# Extract 2 sets of numbers from a string using PHP's preg?

Tags: php, pcre

Here's some PHP code:

```
$myText = 'ABC #12345 (2009) XYZ';

$myNum1 = null;

$myNum2 = null;
```

How do I add the first set of numbers from `$myText` after the `#` in to `$myNum1` and the second numbers from `$myText` that are in between the `()` in to `$myNum2`. How would I do that?

Comment: What do you want $myNum1 and 2 to be in this example?

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/#(\d+).*\((\d+)\)/', $myText, $matches);
$myNum1 = $matches[1];
$myNum2 = $matches[2];
```

assuming you have something like:

" stuff ... #123123 stuff (456456)"

that will give you 
$myNum1 = 123123
$myNum2 = 456456

Comment: Because, with the last number group, I see a ")" in the results!

Comment: The wrong closing paren was escaped. It should be: \\((\d+)\\)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input string of form "123#456", you can do

```
$tempArray = explode("#", $input);
if (sizeof($tempArray) != 2) {
    echo "OH NO! Something bad happened!";
}
$value1 = intval($tempArray[0]);
$value2 = intval($tempArray[1]);
echo "Result: " . ($value1 + $value2);
```